# casting to datetime data to month and year in C#

Tags: c#, t-sql, c#-4.0, datetime

i have linq to entities query below but i want the where clause to use the logic in sample T-SQL code after it.

```
var myList = from p in ctx.myTable
               where !ctx.Report.Any(m =>  m.ReportDate == DateTime.Today && m.ReportDate ==  DateTime.Today)
               select p;
```

How can i compare to month and year in my where clause like in the T-SQL below?

```
WHERE month(R.ReportDate) = month(GETDATE()) AND YEAR(R.ReportDate) = YEAR(GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dealing with dates in LINQ to Entities is a little tricky. <strike>I'm not sure you can generate `MONTH()` or `YEAR()` within your SQL. But</strike> you can definitely generate `DATEPART` call with proper `m` or `y` as datepart.

Use [`SqlFunctions.DatePart` Method (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466176%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do that:

```
var todayMonth = DateTime.Today.Month;
var todayYear = DateTime.Today.Year;

var myList = from p in ctx.myTable
             where !ctx.Report.Any(m => SqlFunctions.DatePart("m", m.ReportDate) == todayMonth && SqlFunctions.DatePart("y", m.ReportDate) ==  todayYear)
             select p;
```

Should generate

```
WHERE DATEPART(m, R.ReportDate) = 2 AND DATEPART(y, R.ReportDate) = 2014)
```

If you really want the `GETDATE()` part, you can use following:

```
var myList = from p in ctx.myTable
             where !ctx.Report.Any(m => SqlFunctions.DatePart("m", m.ReportDate) == SqlFunctions.DatePart("m", SqlFunctions.GetDate()) && SqlFunctions.DatePart("y", m.ReportDate) ==  SqlFunctions.DatePart("y", SqlFunctions.GetDate()))
             select p;
```

**Update**

I just found that page: [CLR Method to Canonical Function Mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which states, that `DateTime.Month` and `DateTime.Year` properties are translated into `MONTH` and `YEAR` methods, so following should work just fine:

```
var myList = from p in ctx.myTable
             where !ctx.Report.Any(m => m.ReportDate.Month == SqlFunctions.GetDate().Month && m.ReportDate.Year ==  SqlFunctions.GetDate().Year)
             select p;
```

Answer (score 0):

A `DateTime` object has `Month` and `Year` property. You can make use of that.

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
            if (dateTime.Month > DateTime.Today.Month) { 
            // Do something
            }

            if (dateTime.Year> DateTime.Today.Year)
            {
                // Do something
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the Following Since DateTime Contains Year and Month.

```
where !ctx.Report.Any(m =>  m.ReportDate.Month == DateTime.Today.Month &&                              m.ReportDate.Year ==  DateTime.Today.Year)
```